# Is it possible to use the Disqus API to get comments from a specific url?

Tags: javascript, json, cross-domain, disqus

I would also like to do this using javascript client-side scripting only if possible.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could always use jQuery for the AJAX calls as almost everything on Disqus is now get.

First you would have to get the thread id from using (http://disqus.com/api/docs/threads/list/):

http://disqus.com/api/3.0/threads/list.json?api_key=API_PUBLIC_KEY_HERE&forum=[shortforumid]&thread=link:[link]

The most important part is for the thread= to have link:[link] as the link: says we are using a URL.

After you get the thread id, you will have to visit (http://disqus.com/api/docs/posts/list/):

http://disqus.com/api/3.0/posts/list.json?api_key=API_PUBLIC_KEY_HERE&thread=[thread id]

Just as a reminder, you do not need to put in the brackets...

Comment: The thread must be an integer...what are you passing as the thread? the section [thread id] is where you insert your thread id (an integer).

Comment: Hi Jaime can you please take a look at my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42403477/cannot-get-the-list-of-comments-related-to-a-specific-thread-using-disqus-api

Comment: your answer is exactly what I want but for some reason I cannot get it worked

Comment: @HamedMinaee - sorry I just saw this, do you have any code that might help? I'm not quite sure what the issue is. I haven't used Disqus in sometime now, so maybe the API changed.

Comment: Thanks. Your API calls worked for me. The shortforumid is your site's shortname (take a look at your Disqus settings in WP under Site Configuration)

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer consists in 2 different calls to Disqus API, to avoid the limit usage you could use only 1 call for obtains a list of comments by an url:

http://disqus.com/api/3.0/posts/list.json?api_key=API_PUBLIC_KEY_HERE&forum=[shortforumid]&thread=link:[link]